# Conda installs packages to default .conda folder. Is it possible to change this folder?

Tags: python, conda

I am using a linux system with a limited home directory space. When I create an environment to a different directory lets say work - which has larger quota- it still installs packages to .conda/pkgs/ folder which takes couple of gigabytes of space.
Is it possible to change this directory?

Comment: Yes, you can configure this directory in your .condarc, see e.g.: https://support.anaconda.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024035613-Shared-Package-Cache

Answer (score -2):

Have you installed `conda` (Anaconda or Miniconda) into your home directory? By default, the installation creates the `pkgs` directory and puts all packages there.

How about installing `conda` (Miniconda) itself into your work directory? Then you're also sure that `conda` can hardlink the packages into your environments in the work directory.